# update kernel without restart

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, upgrade

Recently Linux got a new feature called Live Kernel Patching, which you means you don't have to restart your system to update kernel.

Is there any other kernel which has this feature already or Linux kernel is the first one?

Comment: Note, that this feature you speak of in Linux is slated for 3.20 which hasn't released, and it's meant to handle patches for security fixes, not really full version updates. I guess, if you have all the patches from one version to the next, it might work for that though…

Comment: [The wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating#Existing_systems) can only list applications that are designed with this in mind so I'm _guessing_ Linux may be the first one to do it at the OS level. Also, it should be noted that `ksplice` has been around for a few years `kpatch` (what you're probably referring to) was just developed because of all the restrictions Oracle has put onto people using `ksplice`.